# new android Camera2 Api on nexus 7

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a problem with android Camera2 API on a Nexus 7. I have developed an app on android 4.4.4 that uses the camera to take a picture, and I want to update it for the Lollipop update. I've followed code from this link to make new camera api work: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java

I've tested code on a Nexus 5, and everything works well, but if i try it on a Nexus 7, something goes wrong. This is the error log:

```
12-17 17:01:15.517: W/LegacyRequestMapper(24382): convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
12-17 17:01:15.517: W/LegacyRequestMapper(24382): Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
12-17 17:01:15.518: W/LegacyRequestMapper(24382): Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
12-17 17:01:15.519: W/LegacyRequestMapper(24382): mapAeAndFlashMode - Ignore control.aeMode == ON_AUTO_FLASH;camera does not support it
12-17 17:01:15.519: W/LegacyRequestMapper(24382): convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
12-17 17:01:15.955: I/CameraDeviceState(24382): Legacy camera service transitioning to state CAPTURING
12-17 17:01:21.198: I/RequestQueue(24382): Repeating capture request cancelled.
12-17 17:01:21.198: I/RequestQueue(24382): Repeating capture request set.
12-17 17:01:21.215: W/LegacyRequestMapper(24382): convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
12-17 17:01:21.215: W/LegacyRequestMapper(24382): Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
12-17 17:01:21.215: W/LegacyRequestMapper(24382): Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
12-17 17:01:21.216: W/LegacyRequestMapper(24382): mapAeAndFlashMode - Ignore control.aeMode == ON_AUTO_FLASH;camera does not support it
12-17 17:01:21.216: W/LegacyRequestMapper(24382): convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
12-17 17:01:21.495: E/AndroidRuntime(24382): FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraBackground
12-17 17:01:21.495: E/AndroidRuntime(24382): Process: com.example.newapicamera, PID: 24382
12-17 17:01:21.495: E/AndroidRuntime(24382): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
12-17 17:01:21.495: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at com.example.newapicamera.Camera2BasicFragment$4.process(Camera2BasicFragment.java:285)
12-17 17:01:21.495: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at com.example.newapicamera.Camera2BasicFragment$4.onCaptureCompleted(Camera2BasicFragment.java:324)
12-17 17:01:21.495: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-17 17:01:21.495: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-17 17:01:21.495: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.InvokeDispatcher.dispatch(InvokeDispatcher.java:39)
12-17 17:01:21.495: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.HandlerDispatcher$1.run(HandlerDispatcher.java:65)
12-17 17:01:21.495: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-17 17:01:21.495: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-17 17:01:21.495: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-17 17:01:21.495: E/AndroidRuntime(24382):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
12-17 17:01:21.542: I/RequestQueue(24382): Repeating capture request cancelled.
12-17 17:01:21.580: E/BufferQueueProducer(24382): [unnamed-24382-2] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
12-17 17:01:21.580: E/BufferQueueProducer(24382): [unnamed-24382-2] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
12-17 17:01:21.596: E/BufferQueueProducer(24382): [unnamed-24382-2] queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
12-17 17:01:21.605: W/Camera-JNI(24382): callback on dead camera object
12-17 17:01:21.620: E/BufferQueueProducer(24382): [unnamed-24382-2] queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
12-17 17:01:21.651: E/BufferQueueProducer(24382): [unnamed-24382-2] queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
12-17 17:01:21.688: E/BufferQueueProducer(24382): [unnamed-24382-2] queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
12-17 17:01:21.721: E/BufferQueueProducer(24382): [unnamed-24382-2] queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
```

The line that throws the exception is:

```
int aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The Nexus 7 is a LEGACY-level device when using the new camera2 API, and LEGACY devices have many limitations relative to devices that implement either the LIMITED or FULL levels of the new API.

In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#CONTROL_AE_STATE) for CONTROL_AE_STATE, there's a note:

```
Limited capability - Present on all camera devices that report being at least HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED devices in the android.info.supportedHardwareLevel key
```

which means it's not guaranteed to be present for LEGACY devices, and in fact it won't be, as such devices don't produce AE state information.

Answer (score 2):

Before using any feature of Camera2 API, first you need to check if that feature is supported by device or not. For your case, you can check like below:

```
// CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                        Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                        if (aeState == null ||
                                aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                            mState = STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE;
                            captureStillPicture();
                        } else {
                            runPrecaptureSequence();
                        }
```

For more details you can check official sample code from Google here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

Answer (score 1):

I read today camera2 api is implemented only in nexus 5 and 6 versions of lollipop.

Comment: Where did you read this? camera2 is a supported API in the official release of Lollipop. It was not fully supported when in preview, but now should work fine. I may be wrong, but please include sources for your information.

Comment: I read that Camera2 wasn't support by preview too, but now lollipop release is official!
Because Camera api is deprecated, so i can't use it on my lollipop devices

Comment: You can still use the camera api

Comment: My app already use old Camera API, but after lollipop update, app crash. For this reason i've try to use Camera2 API.

Comment: The simple Camera 2 API example runs on my Nexus 2013 wifi on 5.0.1.  However, it doesn't exercise any of the cool new advanced features.  I've read that the Nexus 7 doesn't have the hardware to support the new RAW output.  Not sure if it supports burst mode or other things.  I'd love to know exactly what it can and can't do with the Camera API.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `result` is a bundle, and `get` returns an `Integer` object (as opposed to an `int` primitive like on the left hand side of the statement). It seems as though the `CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE` is not in the bundle. This may mean that something is not supported on your device, but that is unclear.

The crash occurs because Java is automatically unboxing an `Integer` into an `int`, but the `Integer` here is `null`! This will throw a null pointer exception because Java is trying to convert a null object into an int, hence the warning:

`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference`

A safer way to deal with this is to have `aeState` be an `Integer` so you don't force java to auto-unbox the right side of the statement. Java is trying to help you out, but it can be confusing!

Comment: ok, i've understand what's the problem, but i would know why occours only when i run app on nexus 7!

Comment: It is a device specific issue. See Eddy Talvala's answer for information re: the nexus7